# Tag in form does not work

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I developed a contact form on my [website](http://fabiorabin.com.br/trabalho) but in this form it has a select unde the person will be able to choose a service but I have no idea how to insert this in my code I would like to know if it is possible. At the beginning my code works I just can not capture The services option. Follow my codes and error image on the console
[image]
Realize that in the image the only field that does not appear anything and that of the service

HTMl:

```
<form id="form-elements" onSubmit="return false">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 center">
                        <div id="result"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-border" placeholder="Nome" name="name"
                                   id="name" required></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control input-border" placeholder="E-mail" name="email"
                                   id="email" required></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-border" placeholder="Telefone" name="phone"
                                   id="phone" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select class="form-control input-border" name="service" id="service" required>
                                <option disabled selected>Escolha um serviço</option>
                                <option value="comediante">Comediante</option>
                                <option value="apresentador">Apresentador</option>
                                <option value="ator">Ator</option>
                                <option value="reporter">Repórter</option>
                                <option value="cerimonialista">Cerimonialista</option>
                                <option value="roteirista">Roteirista</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <textarea id="input" class="form-control message-input" rows="7" required="required"
                                      placeholder="Mensagem" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default buttons button-send" id="submit_btn">Quero Contratar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

JS:

```
//Contact Us
$("#submit_btn").click(function() {
    //get input field values
    var user_name       = $('input[name=name]').val();
    var user_email      = $('input[name=email]').val();
    var user_telephone      = $('input[name=phone]').val();
    var user_service      = $('input[name=service] option:selected').val();;
    var user_message    = $('textarea[name=message]').val();

    //simple validation at client's end
    var post_data, output;
    var proceed = true;
    if(user_name==""){
        proceed = false;
    }
    if(user_email==""){
        proceed = false;
    }
    if(user_message=="") {
        proceed = false;
    }

    //everything looks good! proceed...
    if(proceed)
    {
        //data to be sent to server
        post_data = {'userName':user_name, 'userEmail':user_email, 'userTelephone':user_telephone, 'userService':user_service, 'userMessage':user_message};

        //Ajax post data to server
        $.post('contact.php', post_data, function(response){

            //load json data from server and output message
            if(response.type == 'error')
            {
                output = '<div class="alert-danger" style="padding:10px; margin-bottom:25px;">'+response.text+'</div>';
            }else{
                output = '<div class="alert-success" style="padding:10px; margin-bottom:25px;">'+response.text+'</div>';

                //reset values in all input fields
                $('#form-elements input').val('');
                $('#form-elements textarea').val('');
            }

            $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();
        }, 'json');

    }
});

//reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
$("#form-elements input, #form-elements textarea").keyup(function() {
    $("#result").slideUp();
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    $to_Email       = "felipe@agenciafront.com.br"; //Replace with recipient email address
    $subject        = 'Contato para contratação de serviços'; //Subject line for emails


    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

        //exit script outputting json data
        $output = json_encode(
        array(
            'type'=>'error',
            'text' => 'Request must come from Ajax'
        ));

        die($output);
    }

    //check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
    if(!isset($_POST["userName"]) || !isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userMessage"]))
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Os campos de entrada estão vazios!  '));
        die($output);
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_Name        = filter_var($_POST["userName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Email       = filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_Phone =                  $_POST["userTelephone"];
    $user_Service       = filter_var($_POST["userService"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_Message     = filter_var($_POST["userMessage"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_Name)<3) // If length is less than 3 it will throw an HTTP error.
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'O campo nome não pode ficar vazio'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //email validation
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Por favor ultilize um e-mail válido'));
        die($output);
    }

    if(strlen($user_Message)<5) //check emtpy message
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Por favor insira uma mensagem'));
        die($output);
    }


    $message_Body = "<strong>Name: </strong>". $user_Name ."<br>";
    $message_Body .= "<strong>Email: </strong>". $user_Email ."<br>";
    $message_Body .= "<strong>Phone: </strong>". $user_Phone ."<br>";
    $message_Body .= "<strong>Serviço: </strong>". $user_Service ."<br>";
    $message_Body .= "<strong>Message: </strong>". $user_Message ."<br>";



    $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($user_Email) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($user_Email) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";



    //proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(). "\r\n" .
    'Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8';



    $sentMail = @mail($to_Email, $subject, $message_Body, $headers);

    if(!$sentMail)
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Ocorreu um erro tente novamente'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Olá '. $user_Name .' Obrigado pelo seu contato retornaremos em breve.'));
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input[name=service]').val();
```

Service is not an input, its a select. change to

```
$('select[name="service"]').val()
```

Comment: Friend if I want that instead of it only get a value in my select it can catch several? If it is what it would look like because in my select it will be able to select more than one option or seeja would be a <select multiple> and not only a select if I add the multiple in the js code it stops working knows how can I get it to send More than one value

Answer (score 1):

`select` element doesn't have value, that's why you have to get value of selected option. So you get that value like this:

## Edit

As **Todilo** noticed, you are trying to get element with `input` tag, while `select` element isn't `input`.

```
$('select[name="service"] option:selected').val();
```

## Example

```js
console.log($('select option:selected').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option>Option 1</option>
<option selected>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer so i insert in my js and php file? Sorry, I'm still half-naked in programming.

Comment: You did everything just fine as it's working. Just change that one line `var user_service      = $('input[name=service]').val();` with what I provided.

Comment: Friend I made here and it did not work I will edit my code for you to see how I added the same

Comment: Ready the only file that I edited was the js with the line of code that you sent more but yes it did not work